# #include of a system header from a modularized project header file gives "Include of non-modular header inside framework module..." error

Tags: swift, macos, module, frameworks, module-map

I am trying to embed libarchive in a Swift-based framework I am building.

I created a module map to privately include `archive.h` (inside module `libarchive` near the end)

```
framework module X
{
    requires objc, blocks, objc_arc
    umbrella header "X.h"

    private header "XPrivate.h"
    private header "x.h"

    use Darwin.C

    module libarchive
    {
        private header "archive.h"
        export *
    }
}
```

Inside `archive.h`, the following line is causing the error:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

I don't understand why this include isn't being mapped to the correct inttypes module in my SDK.

There is a module Darwin.C.inttypes is defined inside my SDK, here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/.../MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/module.modulemap
```

Can someone tell me how to get the `#include` in `archive.h` to map to the declared module?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? I am also in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

Pretend to be a system framework by changing to  `framework module X [system]`.

Not the correct solution but it seems to work.